# Use of bridgeToObjectiveC() in swift

Tags: ios, swift

What does ***bridgeToObjectiveC()*** will do in swift. It seems like converting a `Swift`  object into `ObjectiveC` object. Is this same as type casting?

For example i can convert a swift `String` into `NSString` like

```
var swingString:String = "test string"
var correspondingNSString = swingString.bridgeToObjectiveC()  // Using bridge

var correspondingNSString = swingString as NSString      // type casting
```

I want to know both are same or not?

Comment: the above is the same as String and NSString are toll free bridged

Comment: It's not clear to me that it's appropriate to use the term "toll free bridged" w/r/t swift. That has a very specific meaning w/r/t CoreFoundation and Objective-C. The swift bridging mechanism looks noticeably different to me.

Comment: @ipmcc the Swift book seems to go out of its way not to use the term where you'd expect them to hit it if it were appropriate (e.g. "Swift's `String` type is bridged seamlessly to Foundation's `NSString` class" in the box out on page 79) so I think your analysis is correct. I guess there is a toll to the bridge, even if its use is seamless, and 'seamlessly bridged' is probably the new appropriate term.

Comment: I don't think they're avoiding the term because there's necessarily some unknown "toll". I think they're avoiding the term because "toll free bridging" refers to a very specific mechanism of interaction between CoreFoundation and Objective-C, and swift's mechanism appears to be fundamentally different.

Comment: Actually, I've had different behavior when converting NSArray and NSDictionaries back and forth using typecasting versus the bridgeToObjectiveC() function. I recommend (for now) using bridgeToObjectiveC() for explicitly bridging obj c and swift objects back and forth.

Answer (score 8):

My understanding is that `bridgeToObjectiveC()` is provided so that you don't necessarily need to know what the corresponding objective-c type is; the compiler decides what the appropriate type is.

For example: if you have an array of `Any` objects can you call `bridgeToObjectiveC()` on each of them with `map` without worrying about whether there are String, Int, and Double values.

Using the `as` keyword allows you to explicitly choose which type you want to cast the value as.