# CGSize sizeWithAttributes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cgsize

In objective-C I was able to use:

```
    CGSize stringsize =
     [strLocalTelefone sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]}];
```

But in Swift Language I didn't found any solution for this situation.

Any Help?

Comment: I can't find a solution to get the size of text in CGSize object...

Comment: I want resize the button to it`s content text...

Comment: @NaldoLopes, just an FYI, typically questions are not re-edited to include the solutions. Questions and answers are designed to be separate. By checking an answer it tells people what the solution you used was.

Comment: ok...my bad... tanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just one line solution:

`yourLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width` for Objective-C / Swift

This will work even your label text have custom text spacing.

Answer (score 160):

what I did is something like this:

## swift 5.x

```
let myString = "Some text is just here..."
let size: CGSize = myString.size(withAttributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)])
```

---

## swift 4.x

```
let myString = "Some text is just here..."
let size: CGSize = myString.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)])
```

---

#### swift 3

```
var originalString: String = "Some text is just here..."
let myString: NSString = originalString as NSString
let size: CGSize = myString.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)])
```

---

#### swift 2.x

```
var originalString: String = "Some text is just here..."
let myString: NSString = originalString as NSString
let size: CGSize = myString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)])
```

Comment: @holex What if I am using Custom font?

Comment: @Developer, obviously you need to use the custom font instead of the system font.

Comment: @holex I am new to Swift. I meant how will I write line of code for that with size?

Comment: @Developer, the `UIFont` class reference can give you more information how you can init a custom font, I would say to take a closer look on the `+fontWithName:size:` method. (here is the complete reference: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/)

Comment: @holex Yes I saw that already but I am not able to call this function in the following line.---- let size: CGSize = myString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)])----. How Helvetica with size 15 can be set in the attribute?

Comment: @holex Any opinion on this?

Comment: @Developer, the line `let size: CGSize = myString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 15.0)!])` works for me with no problem, I'm not sure where you have been stuck at.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64783/discussion-between-developer-and-holex).

Comment: How can i get button text?

Comment: @Virussmca, have you taken a look on the `UIButton` class reference? you would have found a method, called `–titleForState:`, that gives the text of your instance. (_source_: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uibutton_class/index.html)

Comment: @holex: yes i can able to get button text but it gives errors,
can you just edit your answer for getting text size from button ?

Comment: @Virussmca, unfortunately I can't update my answer with that, the OP has no such request of any buttons or its any sizes. If you have a new issue, please raise a new post about it and the community will probably answer to you.

Comment: I have a unicode string so how can i get the size of that string using sizeWithAttributes?

Comment: @NavneetSharma, `String` in Swift fully supports unicode characters, so it should be no difference at all.

Comment: no need for the NSAttributedStringKey.font it can be written as .font
it is inferred to be NSAttributedStringKey ==> 
size(withAttributes: [.font : UIFont(...)])

Answer (score 8):

Just use explicit casting:

```
var stringsize = (strLocalTelefone as NSString).sizeWithAtt...
```

<s>Otherwise you can bridge it too:</s>
Bridging is no longer supported in later versions of Swift.

```
var strLocalTelefone = "some string"
var stringsize = strLocalTelefone.bridgeToObjectiveC().sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)])
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24044717/1429262) is worth at least looking at, as it highlights potential differences between the two approaches.

Comment: The bridge is unnecessary. Swift `String`s seamlessly bridge to `NSString`.

Comment: @Bill true, but bridging allows you to call `sizeWithAttributes` directly, rather than creating a new constant with a name (as shown in the accepted answer). It is less code and basically does the same thing (as bridging gives you an `NSString`). So I would argue creating a new named constant is unnecessary.

Comment: how can i set button titlelabel text in place of "some string"?

Comment: You can just access the button's `titleLabel`: `self.myButton.titleLabel.text`. Is that what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this piece of code, it's easier and you don't have to create new variable just to get NSString object:

```
var stringToCalculateSize:String = "My text"
var stringSize:CGSize = (stringToCalculateSize as NSString).sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)])
```

Answer (score 0):

On xCode 6.3, this is what you need to do now:

```
    let font:AnyObject = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 14.0) as! AnyObject
    let name:NSObject = NSFontAttributeName as NSObject
    let dict = [name:font]
    let textSize: CGSize = text.sizeWithAttributes(dict)
```

Comment: Why are you doing all that weird casting? Why not just do `let dict = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 14.0)!]`

Answer (score -3):

On xCode 8.0, this is what you need to do now:
let charSize = string.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)])

Comment: Swift String type doesn't have this function. This is only for NSString.