# Converting sizeWithFont method to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm going over old obj-c tutorial and having hard time understanding obj-c code. And they are apparantely deprecated.
I've looked into other stackoverflow questions but I still could not figure out since none of them were not in Swift.

```
   CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:textFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(printableFrame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
   CGRect textFrame = CGRectMake(printableFrame.origin.x, currentY, textSize.width, textSize.height);
```

How can I convert above code to Swift?

Comment: I am sure the `–sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` has been deprecated since iOS7.

Answer (score 6):

The method was deprecated in favour of sizeWithAttributes.

[Replacement for deprecated sizeWithFont: in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7)

To convert to swift, unfortunately it looks like you'll have to have to use an NSString in your code

[CGSize sizeWithAttributes in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141610/cgsize-sizewithattributes-in-swift)

Clean, but this will impact performance, so you may want to find another solution if these lines are called a lot.